# Writing a plugin in LAMMPS

Tags: lammps, programming

I am trying to write a plugin in LAMMPS that would need to compute the energy between two atoms as a function of the first atoms coordination number. From the LAMMPS GitHub repository, I found that there is a compute command that can do the calculation of the coordination number. This brings me to the following question: Can I call that from a pair style (let's say gaussian)?

The specifics of the problem are as follows:
I need some way to bias the energies obtained from using pair_style gauss/cut to be dependent on the current coordination number of the central atom. This means that I need to modify the hgauss term in the gaussian on the fly.